# iOS: Track user is driving in background

Tags: ios, swift, location

My goal is to know when the user is traveling even if the app is killed or in the background. So I implemented this:

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

private func setupLocationManager(){

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        locationManager.activityType = .otherNavigation
    }

func startSignificantChangeLocationUpdates() {

        guard CLLocationManager.significantLocationChangeMonitoringAvailable() else {
            logger.error("significantLocationChangeMonitoringAvailable returned false")
            return
        }

        setupLocationManager()
        locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
    }

 func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        // only save data above magical 5m/s => 18km/h
        var  filteredLocations = locations.filter{$0.speed > 5}

        //only save the fastest item if multiple data is delived
        filteredLocations = filteredLocations.sorted { (l1, l2) -> Bool in
            l1.speed > l2.speed
        }
        if let fastestLocation = filteredLocations.first{
            if (filteredLocations.count > 0){
                //save to DB
                locationModel.addLocations(clLocations: [fastestLocation])
            }
        }
    }
```

My problem is that this is not very accurate. Even if I travel more than 10km in 10min by train I just get 2 or 3 datapoints saying that I traveled just 2 minutes.

How can I improve this? `kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters` is using a lot of energy. If I compare with Moves then the data is very accurate. But I don't want to integrate their SDK as I try to protect my users privacy.

Comment: Do you ever call `startUpdatingLocation`?   If not then you will,only get the significant location updates and the parameters you set in `setupLocationManager` are ignored. Location accuracy of nearest 10 meters requires the GPS chip to be powered on. Also, the distance filter should just be a number, not a kCL... constant

Comment: CLLocationAccuracy is a Double if you dig into the framework. I think that's correct. Doesn't startUpdatingLocation keep the app always active (draining battery)?

Comment: If you don't call `startUpdatingLocation` then you will only get significant location updates, which is every 500m and every 5 minutes.  Yes, `startUpdatingLocation` can result in greater battery drain, but that is the trade-off; do you want lower battery usage or more accurate location data.

Comment: I called both  locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
and only had one location in a 30 minutes drive...

Comment: I would start by removing your filtering code in order to confirm the raw data you are getting. My suspicion is that without using "best" accuracy you won't get accurate speed data.